# ANGLE use in Qt.5.9.1

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

In our project we switched from the Qt-Version 5.5.0 to 5.9.1

We are running Software, that runs partially on virtual machines with OpenGL 1.1 (standard I think). With Qt5.5 everything went fine and ANGLE mapped to DirectX correctly. 
Since we are using Qt5.9.1, the OpenGL windows doesn't behave like they should, you can see the behaviour in the picture.

[Difference Qt5.5 and Qt5.9.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8DFM.png)

Is their a bug in the new Qt-version or am I missing something?

Would it change something if we build Qt5.9.1 again with `configure -opengl dynamic`?

P.S.: We changed from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015, but I don't think that this matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem as well and I solved it by compiling a newer version of angle and putting it right next to your exe. Can't run them correctly in QtCreator though (must deploy and then copy).

Comment: Thanks, maybe i will try this. I realized my application only needs OpenGL1.1 and the virtual machines are able to do this. I only had to set QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL) and now it works fine. I don't know, why it worked in Qt5.5 without that attribute, but it does know. Do you know if visual studio uses any ANGLE version? maybe it is going to work their.

Comment: Apparently, there are templates that use angle. https://github.com/Microsoft/angle/wiki/Choosing-a-Visual-Studio-template